# Is the following table in 3NF?

Tags: database, 3nf

I have the following table:

criteria -> (ID,COURSE,REIMBURSEMENTAMOUNT)

The REIMBURSEMENTAMOUNT attribute reflects the percent of the course cost that is reimbursed. I am afraid that this table is not in 3NF because the course depends on the ID and the reimbursement amount on the course. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: what does the ID column represent?  The ID for the course?

Comment: yes, the id for the course.

Comment: Then depending on what `COURSE` is, it's probably not 3NF.  Course related things should be on the Course table (and only there).

Comment: You need to specify what functional dependencies there are between the various possible sets of attributes.  There isn't anywhere near enough information for anyone to be able to assess whether the table is in 3NF.

Comment: Hi. In the definition of 3NF that involves not having transitive FDs of prime attributes on non-prime attributes, X->Y is "transitive" when there's an A where X->A and A->Y *and not A->X*. So if id is 1:1 with course then {COURSEREIMBURSEMENTAMOUNT}->REIMBURSEMENTAMOUNT is not a problem. Learn & use definitions. Since you haven't given all the FDs, you don't seem to know what "normalization" means. Please google 'stackexchange homework' & always reference/quote your textbook & show your work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If Id is the id of the course, then why have both?  Unless this is the only table where the name of the course is, then your table should just be:

criteria -> (ID,REIMBURSEMENTAMOUNT)